# Why sys.exit() dose not shutdown python when there are backgroud threads?

Tags: python, multithreading

```py
import sys
import time
from threading import Thread


def run_forever():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print('running')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = Thread(target=run_forever)
    t.start()
    sys.exit()
```

It seems `sys.exit` can't shutdown the program if I still have any background threads. In this case, how can I gracefully close this program (especially when I can't see all the background threads)?

#### EDIT

I know it's better to keep track of all the background threads. But in this use case I know it's safe to kill them all at once. I just can't find a way to simply close the program.

Comment: "especially when I can't see all the background threads" - keep better track of your background threads. (If you don't have enough control of the relevant code to do that, then you're not going to *get* a graceful shutdown - the best you'll get is a brute-force abrupt shutdown that's likely to leave corrupt files and uncommitted database transactions and all sorts of other mess.)

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Emmm... Maybe what I meant by "graceful" is actually a  brute-force shutdown. How can I do that with just a single line of code? I can close the program in a terminal with `KeyboardInterrupt`, but raising it dosen't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no real reason why this happens other than `sys.exit` is designed to only end the thread it is called from, as you've demonstrated here. There are two options that you can use to get the behavior you're expecting.

1. Use daemon threads. Daemon threads will exit if their parent exits. You can make your code use daemon threads like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = Thread(target=run_forever)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    sys.exit()
```

2. Use `os._exit` This will end your program similar to how I imagine you think `sys.exit()` behaves. This is more of a brute force method and is probably not a good idea, but is possible.

I would recommend using daemon threads unless you absolutely cannot. (i.e. you want to sometimes end just the main thread while the other continue, and sometimes end all of them at once.)
More information on daemon threads: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-daemon-threads/

Comment: Note that the automatic termination daemon threads experience on program end is still a brute-force shutdown that offers no opportunity for cleanup. Particularly, pending `finally` blocks and `__exit__` methods **will not run**.